# Mysql lock same data for multiple delete query with different criteria

Tags: mysql

Mysql Version : **5.7.14-log**

I have following table with 16 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE aggr (
 a_date DATE,
 product_id INT(11),
 data_point VARCHAR(16),
 los INT(11),
 hour_0 DOUBLE(4,2),
 UNIQUE KEY `unique_row` (a_date,product_id,data_point,los),
 INDEX product_id(product_id)
);


INSERT INTO aggr(a_date,product_id,data_point,los,hour_0) 
VALUES
('2018-07-29',1,'arrivals',1,10),('2018-07-29',1,'departure',1,9),
('2018-07-29',1,'solds',1,12),('2018-07-29',1,'revenue',1,45.20),
('2018-07-30',1,'arrivals',2,10),('2018-07-30',1,'departure',2,9),
('2018-07-30',1,'solds',2,12),('2018-07-30',1,'revenue',2,45.20),

('2018-07-29',2,'arrivals',1,10),('2018-07-29',2,'departure',1,9),
('2018-07-29',2,'solds',1,12),('2018-07-29',2,'revenue',1,45.20),
('2018-07-30',2,'arrivals',2,10),('2018-07-30',2,'departure',2,9),
('2018-07-30',2,'solds',2,12),('2018-07-30',2,'revenue',2,45.20);
```

In my application two thread try to execute delete query but it get stuck. So I try to reproduce same thing in Mysql as follow.

**How to reproduce**

Start 2 different session of mysql ( I am using SQLYoug)

Try following query in 1st session

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM aggr
WHERE a_date BETWEEN '2018-07-29' AND '2018-07-29' 
AND product_id = 1 ;
```

Try following query in 2nd session.

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM aggr
WHERE a_date BETWEEN '2018-07-29' AND '2018-07-29' 
AND product_id = 2 ;
```

Now execute following query

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`INNODB_LOCKS`;
```

So above query shows that two different transaction is running and uses same
**lock_mode, lock_space , lock_page and lock_data**

Check following screenshot.
[image]

**So Question**

why two different transaction lock on same data as I am using different delete queries with different product_id ?

Thanks

Comment: If the delete queries are targeting different records, then wouldn't you expect two different locks to be used?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Ideally it should lock two different data to lock , but as you can see in image it lock on same data.

Comment: one lock for product 1 and another lock for product 2. If 3rd session try to update the product 1 or 2 then what happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL locks the rows it looks at when trying to find the rows you want to delete. If it can, MySQL will use an index for this.

Your sample is unfortunately slightly misleading. MySQL is too smart for its own good, so when it realizes that it has to probably read most of the table anyway, it will just do that and read the whole table without the use of a secondary index, thus using the primary key to lock (which, since you don't have one, is in your case the internal `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` listed in `lock_index`). This will in effect just lock all rows.

Using `explain delete FROM aggr WHERE a_date BETWEEN ...` will tell you which index will be used (in the `key`-column). Add some rows for other dates (until `explain` doesn't show `null` for the key anymore), and your sample should work with that *exact* query, as MySQL will start using the using your `unique_row`-index to find the (single) `a_date` and `product_id` without overlapping with the other query (but not a date range).

Your original table probably already has more rows, and you probably would not have investigated if having more rows would solve your problem, so you are probably using a different query. Most likely a different date range (well, an actual range instead of a single date). If you do, your queries will overlap w.r.t. the date, since the index that is most likely to be used (`unique_row`) will lock that complete date range (if it spans more than one day), as it starts with the date. MySQL *may* use the index on `product_id`, but probably doesn't (otherwise you would not have that problem).

So in your case, adding an index `(product_id,a_date)` (or e.g. a primary key that starts with those columns) should make the query only lock the given `product_id`.

Simplifying it a bit (more details about how indexes work can be found e.g. [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html)), MySQL will, in your case, lock all rows that lie between `product_id`/ `start_date` and `product_id`/`end_date`. To know what lies "between", the column order in the index is relevant. In a list that is ordered 1st by `product_id`, then by `a_date`, no other `product_id` lies within in that range (as `product_id = 2` will be ordered behind every `product_id = 1` with every possible date). In a list that is ordered 1st by `a_date`, then by `product_id`, `date = 2018-07-30`/`product_id = 2` will lie between `date = 2018-07-30`/`product_id = 1` and `date = 2018-07-31`/`product_id = 1`. So in the first case (an index `(product_id, a_date)`),  you do not have an overlap between products, while in the second case (e.g. your `unique_row`-index), several products will lie in the lock range if your date range spans more than a single date.

This is rather specific to your (assumed) query (fixed `product_id` and a date range), and if you change the conditions (e.g. use product ranges) or combine that with other queries (otherwise you probably would not need a transaction or you probably would not care if the other query needs to wait for 10ms) or actually only have a handful of rows, you may need to make additional adjustments.

Comment: I have try with adding more 16 rows and surprisingly it work as expected, and it also uses the index in **key** column, How can I make sure that Mysql always use index for scanning the rows ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you (currently) cannot force MySQL to use a specific index on delete. Is a low row count (or a large date range to be deleted) a concern? You may find a solution depending on details of your situation. You can e.g. add a primary key that starts with `product_id` (assuming it is `not null`; maybe include an artifical column to make a unique non-null pk), but then it's specific to queries that delete by `product_id`. Generally, preventing overlapping locks might not be possible in every case, so you may need to adjust your app to support this possibility.

Comment: I have change table from unique key to primary key, but still with around 1116 rows getting the same issue, but now instead of **GEN_CLUST_INDEX** I can see lock_index as **PRIMARY** in INNODB_LOCKS table. In explain mode sql show 192 rows scan. but actually there are only 90 rows for the given criteria , **EXPLAIN DELETE FROM aggr WHERE product_id IN(1) 
AND a_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-05 23:59:59.999';**

Comment: Did you switch the column order for the primary key? It has to *start* with `product_id` (the unique key did not).

Comment: Let me try that too.

Comment: Yes, it is working as expected, But how does the column **order matter in key** ? How to decide in which order I should add column in index ?

Comment: Column order in an index is absolutely important (imagine a "phonebook index" that is ordered by `(phonenumber, name)` instead of `(name, phonenumber)` - both have their use cases, but they cannot be exchanged for each other). I added some explanation to the answer in the context of your situation and hope it gives an idea about how it works (you may want to try that in a spreadsheet program where you order some sample rows by different columns), but I can't give a thorough introduction to indexes here (but I added a link to the MySQL documentation as a starting point).

Comment: I change the unique key (product_id , a_date) now, If I run the query for same product_id i.e(1,2) and different date range then this does not lock the table which is reverse of what you explain in last comment.(1). **DELETE FROM aggr1 WHERE product_id IN(1,2) 
AND a_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-03 23:59:59.999';**  (2). **DELETE FROM aggr1 WHERE product_id IN(1,2) 
AND a_date BETWEEN '2015-01-04 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-06 23:59:59.999';**

Comment: As I said: it was simplified (that's why I wrote "in your case" and "fixed product_id and a date range"). The basic concept is the first sentence: *MySQL locks every row it examines when looking for your rows.* The rest of the answer just explicates this, as that sentence alone would admittingly not have helped you much. But to fully understand which rows are examined, you have to understand how indexes work. I really can't do this here. But as a short addition: `product in (1,2)` is not the same as a range scan that you used for the date. `product between 1 and 3` would be (and should lock).